# How to make sure all enum exist in Array like Record<T, K>

Tags: typescript

```
enum TypeEnum {
  "A" = "A",
  "B" = "B",
}

const ResultArray = [{
  type: TypeEnum.A
}]


/**
 * Property 'B' is missing in type '{ A: string; }' but required in type 'Record<TypeEnum, string>'.
 */
const ResultObj: Record<TypeEnum, string> = {
  [TypeEnum.A]: 'A'
}
```

How to declare ResultArray type to make sure that ResultArray has all the TypeEnum?
Just like ResultObj type define. So ts will tell me that I lose the TypeEnum.B in ResultArray.

Comment: Sounds like you should just be using an object.

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly using TS enums, but const assertions instead:

```
// Feel free to pick a more suiting name...
// If you're going to make an enum where Key is always equal to Value (as strings), 
// you might as well just use a strongly typed, unmodifiable array of Values
// (i.e. a 'const assertion')
const typeEnum = ["A", "B"] as const;
type TypeEnum = typeof typeEnum[number];

// N.B.: square brackets need to be at the end - 
// otherwise you're saying "this array only has one element"
type ResultArray = { type: TypeEnum }[];

// valid
const resultArray: ResultArray = [
  { type: "A" },
  { type: "B" },
  // { type: "C" } -- won't work since "C" is not in `typeEnum`
];

// Alternative: if you want to express required array elements:
// (gets very verbose very fast)
type ResultArray2 = [
  { type: "A" } & Record<string, unknown>,
  { type: "B" } & Record<string, unknown>,
]
const resultArray2: ResultArray2 = [
  { type: "A", foo: "bar" }, // ok
  { type: "B", bar: "foo" }, // ok
  // { type: "C", asd: "efg" }, // type C not allowed
]
```

You can read more about const assertions [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), and more about the weaknesses of TS enums [here](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-trouble-with-typescript-enums)

Comment: If you miss typeEnum.B, ts will not alert.
export const resultArray: ResultArray = [
  { type: 'A' },
];

Comment: Then you could explicitly say

```ts
type ResultArray = [ { type: "A" }, { type: "B" }, ..etc ];
```

Although since it gets very verbose this way, you could consider using a mapped object type instead, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html

Comment: What I want is ResultArray will alert me just like ResultObj. And obviously explicitly say ResultArray make no sense. = =

Comment: Not sure if you can do that in TypeScript with less code than suggested. `And obviously explicitly say ResultArray make no sense. = = –` -- nothing obvious about it at all since you didn't really describe your use case and your reasons for "I want X"... Depending on context it could be the right solution. Alternatively you could think about run-time validations and/or unit tests, and/or already mentioned mapped object types instead.

Comment: Sorry for no fully reason. What I truly want is make sure that when someone add enum to TypeEnum, ts will alert him to deal with the ResultArray just like ResultObj.